# Rellenar tabla HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy teniendo muchos problemas con lo que estoy intentando hacer. Le he dados vueltas y no sé si es posible, que teniendo una tabla creada en HTML, pueda rellenar los dias de cada mes con JavaScript. El código HTML que tengo es el siguiente:

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/semanal.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/estilo.css"/>

</head>
<div style="margin:40px; text-align:center;">
<a id="cmd_prev" href="#">&lt;</a>
<span id="year">2017</span>
<a id="cmd_next" href="#">&gt;</a></div>

<div id="principal_pormeses">
 <!-- CONTENEDOR TRABAJO -->
 <center>
 <ul class="Meses">
  <li>Enero
  <ul class="DiasSemana">
 <p><li>L</li>
 <li>M</li>
 <li>X</li>
 <li>J</li>
 <li>V</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li></p>
 </ul></li>
 <script>

</script>
  <li>Febrero
  <ul class="DiasSemana">
 <p><li>L</li>
 <li>M</li>
 <li>X</li>
 <li>J</li>
 <li>V</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li></p>
 </ul></li>
  <li>Marzo
  <ul class="DiasSemana">
 <p><li>L</li>
 <li>M</li>
 <li>X</li>
 <li>J</li>
 <li>V</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li></p>
 </ul></li>
  <li>Abril
  <ul class="DiasSemana">
 <p><li>L</li>
 <li>M</li>
 <li>X</li>
 <li>J</li>
 <li>V</li>
 <li>S</li>
 <li>D</li></p>
 </ul></li>
 </ul>
 </center>
    <!-- ------------------ -->
</div>
```

Y a partir de aquí no sé si se podrá insertar algún script para obtener cada día del mes. He estado intentando algunas cosas pero no me sale nada. Aún estoy muy verde en JavaScript y me está costando mucho, la verdad. Agradezco toda vuestra ayuda y valioso tiempo.

Comment: seria bueno que agregues una captura de como lo tienes ahora y un posible de lo que deseas lograr para.. tener mas claro tu pregunta

Comment: No sería mejor usar alguna librería de tipo calendario como https://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Sólo tengo la base, el nombre de los meses y el nombre de los días debajo, y me gustaria conseguir algo como : https://fjarabo.webs.ull.es/Calendar/Normal/Anual.htm  @Tegito123

Comment: al link que me enviaste solo da click derecho ver codigo fuente.. y veras todo el script que tiene para llenar los datos

Comment: aqui tienes un gran tutorial: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-build-a-beautiful-calendar-widget--net-12538

Comment: @Tegito123 El link que te he enviado lo he mirado pero la verdad es que no lo entiendo...Respecto al tutorial que me has enviado, como podría verlo de forma anual en lugar de forma mensual?